# AWS API Gateway: how to set expiration for API key

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I google and search all AWS document about AWS API Gateway. It seems that API key is never expired.

If anyone have any idea to manage the API Key (set expiration) , please share your suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove those keys with an external lambda. It is a very bad feature to auto expire, since external integrations will be broken after a period of time.

If something need to be intentionally removed, then it should be controlled externally  via an application.

Docs for Deleting API Key:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#deleteApiKey-property

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation !